# Retrieving Database and play videos c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html5-video

Here is a snippet i made to upload file and displaying uploaded files:
[image]
what i want is to play video instead of the datagrid. I am stuck here how to do this as i am new to asp.net and web services kindly please help me with this :) here is my code:

**ASPX**

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"    CodeBehind="Sample.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication8.Sample" %>
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        debugger;
        var DivElement = $('#MultipleFileUploader');
        var i = $('#MultipleFileUploader p').size() + 1;

        $('#AddAnotherUploader').on('click', function () {
            $('<p><input type="file" ID="FileUploader1' + i + '" name="FileUploader1' + i + '" class="form-control" /> </p>').appendTo(DivElement);
            i++;
            return false;
        });           
    });
</script>

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Uploading Multiple Files</h4>
    <hr />
    <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Choose File</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-10" id="MultipleFileUploader">
            <p>
                <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUploader" CssClass="form-control" />
                <a href="#" id="AddAnotherUploader">Add Files</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnUploadFile" OnClick="BtnUploadFile_Click" 
            Text="Upload Files" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Select Files:</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="DataGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnRowCommand="DataGridView_RowCommand" CssClass="form-control">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="File Name" DataField="Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="File Size" DataField="Size" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Get File">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LbnDownload" runat="server" CommandName="DownloadFile" 
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'>Download</asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Video">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <video  width="300" height="200" autoplay controls>

                                  <Source src='<%# Eval("Name")%> .mp4' />

                           </video>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>



     </div>
</div>
 </asp:Content>
```

** Aspx.cs**

```
    namespace WebApplication8
      {
public partial class Sample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetUploadedFiles();
        }
    }
    private void GetUploadedFiles()
    {
        using (Database1Entities SampleDb = new Database1Entities())
        {
            DataGridView.DataSource = SampleDb.UploadFiles.ToList();
            DataGridView.DataBind();

        }
    }

    protected void DataGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "DownloadFile")
        {
            int File_ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            using (Database1Entities SampleDb = new Database1Entities())
            {
                var File = SampleDb.UploadFiles.Where(f => f.Id.Equals(File_ID)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (File != null)
                {
                    Response.ContentType = File.ContentType;
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + File.Name);
                    Response.BinaryWrite(File.Content);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void BtnUploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpFileCollection File_Collection = Request.Files;
        using (Database1Entities SampleDb = new Database1Entities())
        {
            foreach (string File_Uploader in File_Collection)
            {
                HttpPostedFile Posted_File = File_Collection[File_Uploader];
                if (Posted_File.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    BinaryReader Binary_Reader = new BinaryReader(Posted_File.InputStream);
                    byte[] File_Buffer = Binary_Reader.ReadBytes(Posted_File.ContentLength);
                    SampleDb.UploadFiles.Add(new UploadFile
                    {
                        Name = Posted_File.FileName,
                        ContentType = Posted_File.ContentType,
                        Extension = Path.GetExtension(Posted_File.FileName),
                        Size = Posted_File.ContentLength,
                        Content = File_Buffer
                    });
                }
            }
            SampleDb.SaveChanges();
        }
        GetUploadedFiles();
    }
           }
     }
```

Thanks alot in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you have video files with extension as `.avi` , `.wmv` . If you want them to be playable in browser, you need to follow HTML5 standard for that. It says best way to have HTML5 video in browser is to have `.mp4`, `.ogg` files atleast. MP4 plays in chrome, IE, safari , OGG is for mozilla browser.

**Assumption :** You can done enough handling to convert them to atleast two formats ( MP4, OGG) or added some validation to accept atleast MP4 file.

Now, comes the part, that will make video files playable. Change `asp:boundfield(*)` to template files. Inside ItemTemplate use following to make it playable.

```
<video  width="600" height="400">
  <source src='<%# Eval("filename") %>.mp4' />
  <source src='<%# Eval("filename") %>.ogg' />
</video>
```

`(*)`

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="DataGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnRowCommand="DataGridView_RowCommand" CssClass="form-control">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="File Name" DataField="Name" />..........
```

Here filename should point to actual MP4 file.

Having said all of this, you are free to test with `.avi` and `.wmv` files with video source, check whether that works!

Comment: i used 
` <video  width="600" height="400"> <source src='<%# Eval("Name"); Eval("Extension")%>'  /></video>` but this gives an error on eval

Comment: You can not use two `Eval` inside single `<%# .. %>` .

Comment: still not playing video. just a video box is appeared with controls :/ and used two evals and it worked :) ` <Source src='<%# Eval("Name")%> .<%# Eval("Extension") %>' />`

Comment: That is what i told you earlier, you need to have atlest MP4 file to make it playable, otherwise this will happen. Try uploading an MP4 file , check the behaviour. IF you are storing MP4 file in a directory say /files , then you need to have src = <full_path_toMP4File> i.e. download path.

Comment: i have edited my code and snippet.. it is still not playing video.. does i need to change my .CS file as well???

Comment: You can not change just extension of `avi` file to `mp4` to make it actual MP4 file, you can to encode that to MP4, there are some service like (http://zencoder.com/en/) which does this. Say an e.g., i have an image with .jpg and i want pdf out of that, so if i change that to `file.pdf`, that will never covert to pdf, rather it will be corrupt pdf file. Also check if file name is getting rendered as `"file.mp4.mp4"`?

Answer (score 0):

I think, 
[this link finds useful for you click here](http://www.videojs.com/)  you can download demo project, copy its js, css and html tags and modified according to your needs.

Comment: it is working in demo with .mp4 .wbm but when i am trying to play mp4 its not playing